# Comparing nanosecond precision timestamps in R

Tags: r, timestamp

Although this is a pretty common utility which might be required by many, but strangely google does not show me any matching answers. 
I have a time stamp which in the format `HH:MM:SS.NANOSECONDPRECISION` 9digits after seconds. I have 2 such columns in R and I need to find the difference. I am unable to find how using POSIX we can convert such character time stamps to comparable numbers .

Sent time - 11:20:30.791372292
Receive time 11:20:30.791382216
What's a good way to find difference between these 2 time stamps

Comment: Already down voted. Please comment the reason

Comment: I didn't vote, but please share a reproducible example of such time stamps. You definitely can't use `POSIXct` due to floating point precision and I'm also in doubt regarding `POSIXlt`. You probably need to do the subsecond comparison by extracting these from the character input.

Comment: POSIXlt is in fact using the _same representation_ as POSIXct: both are accurate to 53 bits and hence about 16 digits. We need more here. An integer64-based representation of nanoseconds since the epoch can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it is safe to assume that your times are always on the same date, the following will work.  It recalculates each time as the number of nanoseconds occurring since the start of the day.  It assumes using 24 hours time.

```
sent_time <- "11:20:30.791372292"
receive_time <- "11:20:30.791382216"

convert_nano <- function(x){
  require(magrittr)
  split <- 
    #* split up the time components
    strsplit(x, ":") %>%
    #* convert strings to numerics
    lapply(as.numeric) %>%
    #* convert each component to nanoseconds
    vapply(function(s) sum(s * c(3600, 60, 1) * 10 ^ 9),
           numeric(1))
}

convert_nano(receive_time) - convert_nano(sent_time)
```

If you will encounter times occurring on different days, you may take a similar approach, but may want to consider an upper limit to the number of days that may be between two times.  If you get two many days, you won't be able to represent nanoseconds adequately.

Answer (score 6):

I am about to release a package to CRAN which you can [currently get from GitHub](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/nanotime) which deals with this pretty much in the way suggested by @roland -- as an S3 extension (around packages [bit64](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bit64) and [RcppCCTZ](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.cctz.html).

To take your example:

```
R> sentt <- nanotime("2016-12-21T11:20:30.791372292+00:00")
R> receivet <- nanotime("2016-12-21T11:20:30.791382216+00:00")
R> format(c(sentt, receivet))
[1] "1482319230791372292" "1482319230791382216"
R> format(sentt)
[1] "2016-12-21T11:20:30.791372292+00:00"
R> format(receivet)
[1] "2016-12-21T11:20:30.791382216+00:00"
R> receivet-sentt
integer64
[1] 9924
R>
```

I (currently) use a fixed format for parsing, this is easy to generalize. I also needed to add a date (as you can never parse datetime only with times, it is indeterminate) and for the parse string reason added a TZ offet of 0.

With that we find 9924 nsec aka 9.924 microsec between the two timestamps. In my industry that sounds like a tick-to-trade metric :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle the subseconds separately:

```
times <- c("11:20:30.791372292", "11:20:30.791382216")

library(chron)

fulltimes <- round(as.numeric(times(times)) * 24 * 3600)
subtimes <- as.numeric(gsub(".+(?=\\.)", "0", times, perl = TRUE))

#difference
sprintf("%.9f", fulltimes[2] - fulltimes[1] + subtimes[2] - subtimes[1])
#[1] "0.000009924"
```

You can easily create an S3 class extending chron with this subsecond handling and appropriate S3 methods.